# Is there a reduction concept in artitificial intelligence?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, reductions, artificial-intelligence

Is there a concept for comparing algorithms in *artificial intelligence theory* similar to *reduction* in complexity theory ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)))?

---

> I'm asking this because I was wondering how AI algorithms are to be classified in terms of general applicability. As far as I'm aware, AI techniques are largely classified by which **problem** they are solving rather than how abstract/ general they are. To me, it would make sense to classify algorithms $P$ and $Q$ for different problems in terms of generality by determining whether $P$ can also—potentially by means of  a prior transformation of the input—solve $Q$.
>
> Articles and book references are very welcome!

Comment: How can one problem solve another? What does that mean in terms of sets? What does it mean, practically speaking, for an algorithm to be "more generally applicable" than another?

Comment: I'm not sure if these are rhetorical questions, so here goes: (1) I'm not talking about "one problem solving another" but rather about a technique/algorithm for solving one problem also being applicable to solving another problem. (2) In terms of sets $S_P \supseteq S_Q$  for the set $S_P$ of the problems solvable by way of transforming $P$ (similarly for $S_Q$). (3) An algorithm $P$ is more generally applicable than an algorithm $Q$ if $P$—potentially by way of transformation within a given complexity threshold— may be applied to more problems.

Comment: 1) Sorry, I misread. You write: "such that P′ also solves Q" -- How can one algorithm solve another? 2) I don't understand what you mean by that. In most definitions, each algorithm solves *one* problem. What does "transforming P" mean here? 3) What does "more generally applicable" mean here?

Comment: Can please give helpful example of what you mean? I think you are using some terms in particular, intuitive ways that may not match common definitions; it's therefore hard to answer.

Comment: Well, in complexity theory for example the *SAT-problem* is said to be *reducible* to the *vertex cover problem* by transforming the input (see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity))). It's probably true that I'm not very precise with terminology (I'll edit my question ;-)) In terms of AI what I'm specifically interested in is how approaches based on *logic* may be compared to other approaches (for example *neural networks*, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence#Approaches)).

Comment: Then maybe you should ask that question instead of fumbling to formalize something. ;)

Comment: I think it will be difficult to find a good definition for "AI technique".

Comment: @Raphael I'm specifically interested in whether there is a method for comparing algorithms in AI based on the reduction principle.

Comment: @adrianN Just substitute with "algorithm solving an AI problem".

Comment: @FK82 There is no such notion in complexity theory; we compare *problems* there. Therefore, you'll have to explain from scratch what kind of relation you mean.

Comment: @Raphael I don't understand what your problem is. Complexity theory only discusses problems in terms of algorithms for a specific computational model (such as a tape machine). There is a close relation between problems and algorithms.

Comment: @FK82 Yes, but the notion of reduction is defined on problems, not algorithms. It simply doesn't make sense for algorithms. Therefore, your analogy won't work.

Comment: @Raphael Care to explain how it "doesn't make sense" if problems are discussed precisely in terms of algorithms solving them?

Comment: Please define the exact relation on algorithms you seem to think exists in computability and/or complexity theory.

Comment: From my understanding, a reduction is a computable function $f$ which transforms a problem $B$ into a problem $A$ (within a given complexity constraint). This is formalized by total (word-) functions $f:\Sigma^*\to\Sigma^*$ which transform the language corresponding to a problem into the language corresponding to another problem. Computability is discussed through acceptance by $k$-tape Turingmachines. Hence, if a reduction exists then an algorithm exist which transforms $B$ to $A$. Now, if an algorithm $P$ exists which solves $A$ and $B$ can be reduced to $A$ then $P$ also solves $B$.

Comment: @FK82: Are you asking, for example, if there is some sort of function that transforms something like say a particular generation of a genetic algorithm to a particular neural network, in a way that supplying a particular input to the generation produces the same output as the neural network? (My AI knowledge is iffy so I may be miss using terminology a bit)

Comment: @Dair Yeah, something like that. For example, would it be possible to reduce a neural network algorithm to an algorithm based on first order logic. The more general property would be some kind of *reduction* (e.g. neural network algorithms are reducible to first-order logic algorithms). My question is about whether some kind of *reduction* property is discussed in artificial intelligence theory. P.S.: My knowledge about AI is pretty limited as well, so no worries about correct terminology. ;-)

Comment: I guess the idea is you should treat a procedure as some sort of function/agent. Then consider an agent that maps input to output. $A: I \to O$. Then consider another agent $A' : I' \to O'$ where $I'$, $O'$ may or may not be the same set as $I$ and $O$ respectively. Then the question reduces to considering a function $f$ (with a certain complexity constraint) such that $f : A \to A'$.

Comment: @Dair Yes, that's the basic idea. I've found the concept of [turing reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) for reducing algorithms to one another. Which seems like it applies to this question. But I can't neither argue that it does, nor do I know if it's been discussed in artificial intelligence theory. Hope someone will shed some light on the matter.